# OpenCV blurred capture with USB camera

Tags: opencv, camera, raspberry-pi

I have a [cheap USB camera for RasperryPI](http://www.dx.com/p/no-drive-mini-usb-camera-for-raspberry-pi-black-408731?tc=EUR&gclid=Cj0KEQjwmv7JBRDXkMWW4_Tf8ZoBEiQA11B2ftgdfc-Lr2ELJiXeO8TnpgV0MsGb36Xzd2DyKsUkiC0aAlI58P8HAQ#.WUGD436GPCI) connected to my RaspPI

I'm capturing images from a moving RC car and most of my images are blurred:

[image]
[image]

How could I improve the quality of my captured images?

What is the cause of this? (low fps? low shutter speed?)

Do you know a better camera that I could use for a moving car (is not fast anyway)

Picture taken with car not moving:

[image]

Comment: What does it look like from a stationary car?

Comment: @DanMašek I've added a picture in the original post

Comment: Excellent. Since it's so nice and sharp when it's stationary, I would say it's motion blur due to long exposure times (I suppose that's what you meant by low shutter speed). Can you control that and lower it, perhaps compensating by increasing gain if the image is too dark?

Comment: I tried to set a lower CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE but unfortunately this cheap camera doesn't support it's change:( I'm most probably going to buy Rasperri PI camera module as a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes long exposure time will cause this motion blur. Making the scene brighter will shorten exposure and so improve the sharpness - although in the end you are using a cheap camera with a small sensor so it isn't exactly ideal for this application. Anyway you could try shining some bright lights on the area the car is moving through, see how much the images improve. Cheap camera might take a few frames to adapt to brighter light so make sure it has a good spread over the part of the movement you are recording.

Comment: Interested in what you did and how much this improved the pictures - can you share any examples?

Answer (score 1):

Either it's because the webcam's recording speed, or slow processing or streaming. Generally you can increase speed by lowering the image resolution. Also RPIs have only one usb serial, so that reduces speed significantly especially if you have other USB devices pluged in. You can try disabling other processes that use resources. If low latency video is absolutely necessary you should get an RPI camera module, witch communicates via its own serial terminal.

Comment: In a couple of days I can try with a Rasperry PI camera module, and I could confirm what you said:)

I'm affected by motion blur even when recording at 120x160, so I guess it's about:
* long exposure time (but camera won't allow me setting CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE)
* USB connectivity
* streaming/recording speed?

Comment: I'ts probably camera specific problem, but you can test it on another computer to be sure.Can't help you with  capture set settings, I never actually used them, but not all webcams allow that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are probably looking blurry because of the compression of the stream. That can be better explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_compensation).

Make sure when you set up your capture device, that you have all your settings set correctly using `cv::VideoCapture`'s [set](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a8c6d8c2d37505b5ca61ffd4bb54e9a7c)

Comment: A 6 Euro VGA camera will at most do MJPEG (if at all, it's hardly necessary), which doesn't do interframe compression, so this is unlikely to be relevant.